# Using `git status` to indicate how many commits I am ahead on `dev` branch

Tags: git, github

I create new branch `dev` and switch to it:

`git branch dev`

`git switch dev`

I do a couple rounds with:
`git add .`
`git commit -m "Desc"`

If I then do on dev branch:
`git status`
It does not show me:
`Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by x commits`

If I do the same on the master branch it shows the message:
`Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by x commits`

Anyone knows why?
How to figure out how many commits I am ahead on my dev branch?

PS C:\workspace\SignalRIntroduction\SignalRDemo> git branch -vv

dev    1fed4e6 Blah

- master f53c56b [origin/master: ahead 8] haha

Comment: _Is there_ an `origin/dev`? Is that set as the upstream for your local `dev`?

Comment: I thought that if I created `dev` branch there is automatically created by git  upstream origin/dev? I am just beginner in git.

Comment: No, `git` doesn't assume when you create the branch that it should create one on the remote (or even that you _have_ a remote, you can use it entirely locally).

Comment: But it does seem to do it for the `master` branch. I don't understand that. Why it shows how many commits I am ahead on `master` branch but not on `dev` branch?

Comment: I am coming from svn concept and trying to grasp the git concept.

Comment: `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/dev dev && { git fetch origin dev:dev || git pull origin dev }`

Comment: A workaround is to run `git rev-list --count dev..HEAD` to get how many commits the current branch is ahead of `dev`.

Comment: So by default git does not create remote for branch - the only exception is master branch - is this true?

Comment: "*So by default git does not create remote for branch - the only exception is master branch - is this true?*" No. See [`git help checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutemltbranchgt): "*If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name…*" We don't know what is going on in your repository. [Edit] and show us the text output of `git branch -vv`

Comment: OK. See the original post.

Comment: `master` has `origin/master` as the upstream branch but `dev` doesn't for some reason. Very much depends on when and how it was created. To set upstream branch: `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/dev dev`